# JavaScript: I Can't import anything

Tags: javascript, import, lit-html

How can I import lit-html in my code?
I Have this codes:

the `index.js` file in `js` folder:

```
import { html } from "lit-html";
myDiv = html`
    <div>
        <a href="">Hello, Click Me!</a>
    </div>
`;
document.body.innerHTML += myDiv;
```

and the `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JS Tests</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I getting an Error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lit-html". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Comment: Maybe do what error message says? Prepend `lit-html` with `/`, `./`, or `../`

Comment: Why do you need a librairie to create HTML?

Comment: https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/140

Comment: you probably haven't installed it yet.

Comment: @Nicolas because I want to color my html codes in JavaScript file.

Comment: @MudiagaEjenavi Yes... Nithin Thampi's Answer is helpful.

Comment: any solution to this if you simply want to include the script in your file (not install via npm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
import {render, html } from "https://unpkg.com/lit-html@0.7.1/lit-html.js"
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JS Tests</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
import {render, html } from "https://unpkg.com/lit-html@0.7.1/lit-html.js";
const myDiv = html`
  <div>
    <a href="">Hello, Click Me!</a>
  </div>
`;

render(myDiv,document.body);
```

Please note that if you are using modules on browser (like above),each import will make a network call. You can use some module bundlers like webpack to build a single JS file (with all dependencies) before you ship the code to browsers.

Comment: im curious as to why none of the documentations point this out.